Retrieve hypervisor host/session id from inside guest VM
I have a VMware VM which is quite sensitive. It needs to be scheduled at max. 500 ms or otherwise it will restart itself. In case there is some heavy process in parallel with the VM (e.g live migration/snapshots), most likely the VM will encounter an restart. In VMware I use vmguestlib in order to retrieve the Session ID. This ID changes when above operations happen and in this way I can detect the cause of the restart. Now I want to use this VM also on KVM based hypervisors (Proxmox, Nutanix, oVirt) and also on Hyper-V. But I couldn't find anywhere information about how could I get some identifier (like in VMware) to help me figure out if those operations happens.
One very important thing is that I have NO control over the hypervisor's host node. So I would need a solution that implies exclusively the guest VM (my VM). Do you have any idea if such thing exist on the mentioned hypervisors? Or there is another way to detect such operations?
I couldn't find anything about this subject. Only how host communicates with guest.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
